# In SQL (Impala) how to calculate time delta between rows that satisfies condition and next one?

Tags: sql, impala

I have a transactional data table, with a structure similar to this:

```
User          Event                    TimeStamp
 u1         listen_music      2017-10-18 13:28:43
 u1         click_btn         2017-10-18 13:28:53
 u1         logout            2017-10-18 13:29:55
 u2         login             2017-10-19 13:30:20
 u2         listen_music      2017-10-19 13:33:25
 u2         visit_home        2017-10-19 13:34:10
 u2         listen_music      2017-10-19 13:36:15
 u2         listen_music      2017-10-19 13:37:35
 u2         visit_profile     2017-10-19 13:40:35
```

I would like to know how long did user listen to music.
So the output would be something like:

```
User        No    Delta
 u1         1      10 sec
 u2         1      45 sec
 u2         2      80 sec
 u2         3      180 sec
```

I don't want to calculate all time deltas and then filter to 'listen_music' events, as there are many other (irrelevant) events.

So actually I want to calculate time delta between a row that satisfies a condition and the next row for all users.

I'm using Impala, but other solutions are also welcomed.

Comment: You've tagged 2 completely different RDBMS here (SQL Server and MySQL), and according to [tag:impala], it's for Hadoop and Oracle, not SQL Server or MySQL. Please update your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select 
    user, 
    row_number() over(partition by user order by timestamp) no,
    delta
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        unixtimestamp(lead(timestamp) over(partition by user order by timestamp))
            - unixtimestamp(timestamp) delta
    from mytable t
) t
where event = 'listen_music'
order by user, no;
```

The subquery computes the difference between the current and the next record of the same user. The outer query filters on the target event and numbers the records using `row_number()`.

Comment: In this way, first, the time difference calculation will run for all events, and only at the end the will the where clause filter to 'listen_music' events, no?
The problem is that 'listen_music' event is only 1% of all events. So there will be a lot ofredundant calculations, if I'm right.

Comment: @rainbowfighter: yes. Since you want the difference with the *next* record, you cannot filter before computing the deltas.